# postgres (timescaledb): merge two views more efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, timescaledb

Try it out: https://db-fiddle.com/f/4XzRZw5DxHML7bYy1mNMmY/1

DB-dump from 2022-10 and 2022-11: https://easyupload.io/1yh4wj

I query my gas heating device and save the data in a Postgres database. For time series I use timescaledb.

I then aggregate various metrics over a month (heating water vs heating building, active burner time ...) to plot some graphs.

A record looks like this, I added english translations with "--"

```
timest               | 2022-12-18 15:49:07+01
temp_warmwasser_ist  | 53.2 -- hot water actual temperature
temp_warmwasser_soll | 54 -- hot water set temperature
temp_vorlauf_ist     | 51.3 -- flow temperature 
temp_kessel_ist      | 51.3 -- boiler temperature 
temp_abgas           | 40.5 -- exhaust gas temperature
temp_raumsollm1      | 20 -- room temperature
temp_raumsollm2      | 20
brenner_stunden      | 13330.1 -- burner active in cumulative hours
brenner_starts       | 15026 -- amount of burner starts 
brenner_status       | 0 -- burner status (1 = on, 0 = off)
alarm_status         | 0 -- alarm
betrieb_2301         | 0 -- 
betrieb_2323         | 1 -- 
ventil               | 3 -- which heating circuit is active 1 = warmwater, 3 = building
pump_power           | 0
brenner_power        | 0 -- burner power
```

To aggregate I use these views:

```
                               View "public.v_heizung_ww_hz"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------
 time   | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain   |
 ww     | double precision         |           |          |         | plain   |
 hz     | double precision         |           |          |         | plain   |
View definition:
 SELECT date_trunc('month'::text, heizung.timest) AS "time",
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN heizung.ventil = 3 THEN heizung.brenner_status::integer
            ELSE 0
        END)::double precision / sum(heizung.brenner_status)::double precision AS ww,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN heizung.ventil = 1 THEN heizung.brenner_status::integer
            ELSE 0
        END)::double precision / sum(heizung.brenner_status)::double precision AS hz
   FROM heizung
  GROUP BY (date_trunc('month'::text, heizung.timest));
```

What I am doing here is summing up the time which circuit is heated up to get a ratio of warmwater vs. building heating.

Output:

```
          time          |         ww         |         hz
------------------------+--------------------+--------------------
 2020-04-01 00:00:00+02 | 0.0254730713245997 | 0.0941775836972343
 2020-05-01 00:00:00+02 |  0.199101468332238 |  0.800898531667762
```

But I also want to get the actual hour count and gas consumption (0.65 empirically determined):

```
                               View "public.v_heizung_monthly"
 Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description
---------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------
 time    | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain   |
 stunden | double precision         |           |          |         | plain   |
 Gas %   | double precision         |           |          |         | plain   |
 Gas l   | double precision         |           |          |         | plain   |
View definition:
 SELECT date_trunc('month'::text, v_heizung_daily."time"::timestamp with time zone) AS "time",
    sum(v_heizung_daily.stunden) AS stunden,
    sum(v_heizung_daily.stunden) * 0.65::double precision / 50::double precision AS "Gas %",
    sum(v_heizung_daily.stunden) * 0.65::double precision AS "Gas l"
   FROM v_heizung_daily
  GROUP BY (date_trunc('month'::text, v_heizung_daily."time"::timestamp with time zone))
  ORDER BY (date_trunc('month'::text, v_heizung_daily."time"::timestamp with time zone));
```

Output:

```
          time          |     stunden     |      Gas %       |      Gas l
------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------
 2020-04-01 00:00:00+02 |  36.64990234375 | 0.47644873046875 | 23.8224365234375
 2020-05-01 00:00:00+02 | 156.43017578125 | 2.03359228515625 | 101.679614257813
```

`v_heizung_daily` looks like this:

```
                            View "public.v_heizung_daily"
 Column  |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description
---------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------
 time    | date             |           |          |         | plain   |
 stunden | double precision |           |          |         | plain   |
 starts  | double precision |           |          |         | plain   |
View definition:
 SELECT s.timest::date AS "time",
    s.brenner_stunden::double precision - lag(s.brenner_stunden::double precision, 1) OVER (ORDER BY s.timest) AS stunden,
    s.brenner_starts::double precision - lag(s.brenner_starts::double precision, 1) OVER (ORDER BY s.timest) AS starts
   FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON ((heizung.timest::date)) heizung.timest,
            heizung.brenner_stunden,
            heizung.brenner_starts
           FROM heizung
          ORDER BY (heizung.timest::date) DESC, heizung.timest DESC) s;
```

**Long story short:**
The issue is then when combining those views. I use this join:

```
select a.time, stunden, stunden*0.65*7 as "kWh", ww, hz, "Gas %", "Gas l", "Gas l"*ww as "ww_l", "Gas l"*hz as "hz_l" from v_heizung_ww_hz a join v_heizung_monthly b on a.time = b.time;
```

Which takes a long time:

```
          time          |     stunden     |       kWh        |         ww         |         hz         |      Gas %       |      Gas l       |       ww_l        |       hz_l
------------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------
 2020-04-01 00:00:00+02 |  36.64990234375 | 166.757055664063 | 0.0254730713245997 | 0.0941775836972343 | 0.47644873046875 | 23.8224365234375 | 0.606830624687273 | 2.24353950955809
Time: 1546.846 ms (00:01.547)
```

So I am wondering if there is a better way to do this 2 queries. I think I have some flaws that makes this operating take this so long. Or should I use materialized views? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I see two views getting monthly heizung aggregation data each. But in the second one you refer to another daily heizung view. What does that view look like? Why are you using the heizung table in the first view, but the heizung daily view instead in the second?

Comment: Two views: v_heizung_ww_hz and v_heizung_monthly ... unfortunate naming ... I added the v_heizung_daily view.

Comment: There's a lot going on in your queries, and I don't see any way to speed the join up, other than speeding up the single views with appropriate indexes that may ease aggregation (function indexes on `heizung(date_trunc('month'::text, v_heizung_daily."time"::timestamp with time zone))` and `heizung(timest::date)` maybe?) I'm not a PostgreSQL guy, though. Maybe others know better ways.

Comment: Do you have a demo set up? How many rows are in `heizung`? And as an aside, does getting rid of the order by in the `v_heizung_daily` help at all?

Comment: Yep, that was well spotted by Cole. `ORDER BY` in views are superfluous, because a view result is considered unordered data anyway. If PostgreSQL really sorts the data instead of optimizing the order by clauses away, then this can slow the queries down.

Comment: `heizung` has 1453185 entries, ~1 minute resolution. I don't downscale or remove old data (yet?).

Comment: @Cole sadly no, where can I do that?

Comment: A lot of people would use https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to create a demo. You would mainly provide DDL for the `heizung` table and then populate it with a couple of records (it can all be made up!). I am not sure the server you are storing the data on, but 1.4 million records can take time - one double precision column would be 1 GB so if this is on your local computer, it would probably need to do a lot of file i/o instead of doing calculations in RAM.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4XzRZw5DxHML7bYy1mNMmY/1

I random sampled some values between August and December (all real). Yes this runs on a server with 1TB nvme, 6 cores i5-8500T, 32GB RAM

Comment: I'm intrigued so I installed postgresql. When I try to select from v_heizung_ww_hz it throws a divide by zero error. In the dataset, there are only 3 results where `brenner_status` is one. Is it supposed to be `COUNT(*)` instead of `SUM`? Or at the very least, I will start with `COUNT(*)` to see what kind of results I get but let me know if you have other suggestions to resolve. Also if you want me to be notified, please @ my username because otherwise I do not get notified.

Comment: @Cole thanks for trying. I uploaded the whole set (2022-10, 2022-11) here https://file.io/ceSVFImKlrXI as db-fiddle had problems with the ~12MB text. I imported it in pg11 and tried it, no more division by zero errors.

Comment: BTW, I tried but the file didn't seem to exist anymore. I would say, if you can prevent duplicates from being inserted, that would at least allow you to remove the `DISTINCT` statement in your `v_heizung_daily` statement. You could either do that on the insertion or you could routinely run a procedure to remove the duplicates. I'm not sure how much it would affect - it's nice knowing they're 15 minute intervals but if there is no change, I would say it'd be better to remove readings that are the same other than the timestamp.

Comment: Oh, had no idea it timed out so quickly. Here another link: https://easyupload.io/1yh4wj

Comment: @Cole I will try to deduplicate, right now a lot of values have some tiny differences.